# I’m looking for short story I read as a teenager, possibly by Heinlein. Story about a society where people can be armed in public

Tags: story-identification

I’m looking for a story about a young man living in a society where individuals can carry a weapon, but must display a badge to indicate to others that they are carrying a weapon.

Comment: What about this story is science fictional or fantastical?

Comment: Could the badge have meant that they were *not* armed?

Comment: When were you a teenager?  Heinlein wrote stories like this in the 1950s-1960s, L. Neil Smith wrote stories like this in the 1980s (first came out in 1978, actually).  There are probably others, too.

Comment: It's been a long time since I read them, but this is making me think of H. Beam Piper's stories where everyone goes armed, stories like *A Planet for Texans*.

Comment: I bet in Star Ship Troopers people carry guns.

Comment: A longer story that was answered in here for me has similar issues https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232037/sf-book-early-1980s-galactic-gunfighter

Comment: @releseabe:  In *Starship Troopers", not  even the police carry guns.  You may want to actually read the book.  It is very unlike that travesty of a movie.

Comment: i did read the book but years ago. in the movie, it seems like veterans would have guns or perhaps the government made sure that no one had weapons at all.

Comment: @releseabe: None of the above.  Guns were legal (as far as I can tell.)  It's just that no one felt the need to carry weapons.

Comment: The society was in one of the Lazarus Long books by Heinlein. I don't remember which one.

Answer (score 28):

In [*Beyond this Horizon* by Robert Heinlein,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_This_Horizon) most people go armed.  Unarmed people are the exception rather than the rule.

Unarmed people wear clothes to be distinctive - so as to not get involved in duels.

Comment: That's the one I had in mind. The unarmed folks wore badges/armbands called "brassards". https://sciencefictionruminations.com/2013/02/03/book-review-beyond-this-horizon-robert-a-heinlein-magazine-1942/

Comment: Agreed. At one point the protagonist is getting drunk at a bar, and the barman says he won't feel comfortable serving him any more unless he gives the barman his gun; and lets him lend him a brassard.

Answer (score 2):

It could be "[The Weapon Shop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Weapon_Shop)" by A E Von Vogt, but I do not recall the story having a badge as a story element.

Comment: In *The Weapon Shops of Isher*  not everyone is armed.  The weapon shops arm people to help them against an oppresive government .  Very few ordinary citizens are armed in those stories.  Also, the weapons are illegal.  The government can't do anything about the shops because of shielding and some kind of lie dectector like thing that unerringly picks out the undercover agents who try to infiltrate the weapon shops.